# ShiftValues form reaptertext box to another textbox

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have an `asp:repeater`  which has two textboxes. On clicking a button (the button is outside the repeater ), all the values in textbox1 should be added to textbox2 like this

```
txtprice2.val = txtprice1.val + txtprice2.val;
```

The repeater markup is

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table id="tbl_priceCal" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    ItemNo
                </th>
                <th>
                    Name    
                </th>
                <th>
                    Price1
                </th>
                <th>
                    Price2
                </th>
            </tr>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <%#Eval("ItemNo")%>
            </td>
            <td class="Name">
                <%#Eval("Name")%>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtprice1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("txtprice1")%>'></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtprice2" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("txtprice2")%>'></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

How can do it using jQuery?

Comment: Please provide some code to show what you've tried so far. This will make it much more likely for people to want to help you than asking for a full-blown solution based on a vague description. Please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please edit the question to add more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way will be to assign two CSSClass price1 and price2 to the txtPrice1 and txtPrice2.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtprice1" runat="server" 
    Text='<%#Eval("txtprice1")%>'
    CssClass="price1">
</asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtprice2" runat="server" 
    Text='<%#Eval("txtprice2")%>'
    CssClass="price2">
</asp:TextBox>
```

Then on click of the button write this.

```
$("#some_button").on("click", function () {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".price1").each(function () {
        var price1TextBox = $(this);
        var price2TextBox = price1TextBox.closest("tr").find(".price2");
        var price2NewValue = +price1TextBox.val() + +price2TextBox.val();
        price2TextBox.val(price2NewValue);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//var TextBoxes1 = $( "input[id*='txtprice1']" );
//var TextBoxes2 = $( "input[id*='txtprice2']" );

$("input[id*='txtprice1']").keyup(function(){
    $( "input[id*='txtprice1']" ).val($( "input[id*='txtprice2']" ));
});


});
```

hope will help you.